# OpenVPN connection cannot find route to direct domains, but to subdomains

Tags: vpn, dns, openvpn, nas, domain

I have an OpenVPN server running on my NAS at my home network, as well as a DNS server, which has a record `nas1` (plus some subdomains) routing to the NAS itself, which I'm using to access different websites and network drives on the NAS. Now while I'm on the road I'm tunneling to my NAS via my router's domain service, using this client configuration:

```
dev tun
tls-client

remote [my-home-domain].myfritz.net 1194

#redirect-gateway def1

allow-pull-fqdn
route 192.168.178.29 255.255.255.255 vpn_gateway ; local IP of the NAS
route nas1 255.255.255.255 vpn_gateway

dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1 ; VPN gateway of the server

pull
proto udp

script-security 2


comp-lzo

reneg-sec 0

cipher AES-256-CBC

auth SHA512

auth-user-pass
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
</ca>
```

I am dealing with the issue now that I'm neither able to access my network drives nor my websites via direct domain like `https://nas1/...`, but curiously I can access subdomains like `https://ns.nas1/`, which I have no explanation for. Does someone else have an idea?

Some things to note:

- The line `route nas1 255.255.255.255 vpn_gateway` is rather decorative right now - OpenVPN also fails to resolve the domain.
- All of `ping`, `tracert` and `nslookup` (on my Windows notebook) succeed in finding a connection via subdomain, but not the direct domain as well. Using `traceroute` and `nslookup` on my NAS' console can find all domains.
- I am aware that I could simply set up my domain in the `hosts` file, but I'm sometimes wanting to access the network with different clients, some of them being Android or iOS, which won't let you set up a domain that easily. I'd like to keep individual client configuration efforts as low as possible.
- If everything fails I'll just use another subdomain for everything I use the direct domain for, although I don't think this is a real elegant solution.

Comment: Not sure i understand the question exactly. What are you trying to reach with https:// nas1 /  ? You also wont get much back from pinging or tracing a domain, you ping a host in a domain.

Comment: E.g. a simple file like `index.php` on the web root via `https://nas1/index.php`. Can access it on my browser just fine when I'm directly in my home network, but when I'm connected via VPN it only works by subdomain like `https://ns.nas1/index.php`. This also extends to network drive folders like `\\nas1\web` (should mention I'm working with WIndows here). Can connect to that at home no problem, but via VPN it won't find the host name. In short, the raw top level domain can't be resolved through VPN, but its subdomains can, and I'd like to find out why and how to work around it.

Comment: I've never heard of a domain name being allowed to be without extension, i'm curious what DNS service you have running. Regardless, if you setup a CNAME record for your domain (lan1) and set up a 301 redirect to your website (ns.nas1) you should be able to connect to nas1. Though in all fairness, it sounds like you have some terms mixed up or i seriously need to look up domains without extensions :) It sounds like you have device names and domains somewhat mixed up.

Comment: I have a Synology NAS where I'm running the DNS Server provided through the Package Center. Fun thing is that my router directed me to access my NAS by device name as well, then I originally resorted to a DNS server for subdomains. I've used the same name for my domain though. I think you might be right with both though, I'm not that experienced with DNS and picking an extensionless domain might just not be the right way to do it.

Comment: Well the thing is, is that your openvpn setup seems fine, except for the extenionless domain. If possible, i would switch to something like mydomain.local and work from there. I'm not familiar with Synlogy's DNS service, but looking at their own documentation its not very friendly. I found https://robpickering.com/configuring-synology-for-forward-and-reverse-internal-dns-resolution/ , while older, to be much clearer. Its oriented for a local, private domain (he uses example.com, but please never use that or any domain extension that is real) and explains some DNS terminology.

Comment: Guess I'll extend my domain for good then. The downside though will be that subdomains don't work with my other VPN connections, but that's an issue on its own... might ask that on here soon. And yeah, Synology's documentation unfortunately tends to be really lackluster, I still got the server set up correctly somehow. And of course I'll stick to TL domains like `nas1` and `lan`. Nevertheless, thanks for your insight.